# Support for usbredir in ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, server, usb, live-usb

Is it possible to use [usbredir](https://www.spice-space.org/page/UsbRedir) package in ubuntu? I have searched and found [usbredirserver](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/usbredirserver) package which by name I guess is the server side of `usbredir`. I have also tried running it by attaching to a particular USB. It looks like server runs well. But I am not able to figure out what kind of client I can use to access USB hosted by the server.